# RewriteRule for Gmail Email Addresses

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to create a rewrite rule for unsubscribe URLs so that the url

```
https://example.com/unsubscribe/myemail@example.com/
```

will be re-written to

```
https://example.com/unsubscribe.php?email=myemail@example.com
```

In the past I've always used the following rule with no problems

```
ReWriteRule ^unsubscribe/(.*)/?$ /unsubscribe.php?email=$1 [NC,L]
```

However, when testing this recently, it seems to be replacing the "+" character (as is used commonly with gmail tagging, for example "myemail+spam@example.com") with an empty space, creating an email address different to the one entered by the user. This is a problem. You can see an example here:

[Example Rewrite Rule Processing](https://htaccess.mwl.be?share=871bad07-b421-50bc-83e4-7b6fbb762360)

I don't really get why this is happening as the "(.*)" filter should allow any character any number of times, shouldn't it?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the mod-rewrite B flag in your rule:

```
ReWriteRule ^unsubscribe/(.*)/?$ /unsubscribe.php?email=$1 [NC,L,B]
```

From the apache mod-rewrite flag manual :

`The [B] flag instructs RewriteRule to escape non-alphanumeric characters before applying the transformation.
In 2.4.26 and later, you can limit the escaping to specific characters in backreferences by listing them: [B=#?;]. Note: The space character can be used in the list of characters to escape, but it cannot be the last character in the list.
mod_rewrite has to unescape URLs before mapping them, so backreferences are unescaped at the time they are applied` .